# Ionic 3: ion-scroll doesn't work

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-scroll

I'm using Ionic version 3.19.0. I'm trying to use "ion-scroll" to zoom in and scroll an image. Sadly, this does not seem to be working, I'm using the following code:

SCSS file:

```
page-contact {
ion-scroll {
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
}
}
```

HTML file:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-scroll scrollX="true" scrollY="true" zoom="true">
      <img src="assets/imgs/debugMap.png" alt="Map">
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

The image displays fine, but I'm not able to either zoom or scroll. I can't seem to find why this is the case. Is my code wrong or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using fixed width and height for ionScroll. 100vh and 100vw..

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Setting the width to 100vw and height to 100vh lets me scroll vertically, but scrolling horizontally and the zooming functions still don't work. Do you happen to know a fix for this or an alternative for using ion-scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for scrolling, but zoom not working is a known-open issue: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5701